# Scraping multiple URLs: No connection adapters were found for {url!r}

Tags: python, string, web-scraping, request

I thought I came pretty far with scraping this website:

`https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/s/?page=2&searchtext=boek&view=list&sort=relevance2&rating=all`

My code tries to get the results for multiple pages - for which you can amend the above-mentioned URL. However, when I create a list of URLs with a dynamic 'page' element I get the following error message;

`No connection adapters were found for {url!r}`

`requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for "['https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/s/?page=1&searchtext=boek&view=list&sort=relevance2&rating=all', 'https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/s/?page=2&searchtext=boek&view=list&sort=relevance2&rating=all']"`

What am I missing here, I feel like I'm close :-)

This is my full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import re
#############################

pages = list(range(1, 3)) #pages

urls = [f"https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/s/?page={page}&searchtext=boek&view=list&sort=relevance2&rating=all" for page in pages]

# Send a request to the URL and get the HTML response
response = requests.get(urls)

dfs = []

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Your scraping logic here
```

Comment: You can not give a list of URLs to `requests.get()`.

Comment: I believe I did so with a different scraper though?

Comment: How would you suggest to proceed?

Comment: Try to provide your code as [mcve], by removing all unnecessary passages, in which case you will notice that you have left something uncommented.

Comment: fair point - does this help?

Comment: Recap exactly why you need the request with the `list`(urls) in the example, if you want to iterate it at a later time to send individual requests.

Comment: i dont think you need this line `# Send a request to the URL and get the HTML response
response = requests.get(urls)` which is causing the error. as you are looping the `url` in a loop.